# JogAmp / JOGL - how does sbt pick up the right native jar?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, raspbian, jogl

I want to try out the JogAmp JOGL build, so I find this artefact on Maven Central:

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22jogl-all%22

That is, there is a main `jar`, and a number of architecture specific jars: `natives-android-aarch64.jar`, `natives-android-armv6.jar`, `natives-linux-amd64.jar`, `natives-linux-armv6.jar`, `natives-linux-armv6hf.jar`, etc.

Now I want to build an application in Scala that I can test on my Linux desktop - the architecture would be `natives-linux-amd64.jar` I guess -, and then deploy on a Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian Jessie - the architecture would probably be `natives-linux-armv6.jar` (or `natives-linux-armv6hf.jar`?).

How do I tell sbt to download the right libraries on each platform?

```
libraryDependencies += "org.jogamp.jogl" % "jogl-all" % "2.3.2"
```

What else?

---

**Edit:** Like now I found the `MovieCube` source, but trying to run it with any type of switch (`-es2`, `-es3`, `-gldef`, `-gl3`) just gives me the following:

```
url_s null
file_s /home/foo/Documents/foo.mp4
stream file:/home/foo/Documents/foo.mp4
vid -1, aid -1
textureCount 4
forceES2   true
forceES3   false
forceGL3   false
forceGLDef false
swapInterval 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile
    at com.jogamp.opengl.test.junit.jogl.demos.es2.av.MovieCube.main(MovieCube.java:555)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

...where my guess is I'm missing some native libraries?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and follow our instructions in our wiki: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#IntelliJ_IDEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the architecture specific jars as a dependencies by specifying the correct classifiers.

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val architecture = Seq(
    "natives-linux-amd64",
    "natives-linux-armv6"
  )
  "org.jogamp.jogl" % "jogl-all" % "2.3.2" +: architecture.map(
    "org.jogamp.jogl" % "jogl-all" % "2.3.2" classifier _
  )
}
```

Comment: So I just link to all possible architectures at the same time?

Comment: Take a look at what's inside the native packages. The classes and native libraries reside in unique directories for each architecture. So I expect it work this way without conflict. But I didn't do a real test. Try it yourself. Good luck! :P